# Dynamic memory only being accessible inside function call

Tags: c

I am creating dynamic memory using malloc() and it works within the function that created it, but after that function ends it no longer works. I am trying to make it so that the dynamic memory that is created within a function can be accessed even after the function that it is created within ends.

```
typedef struct ListObj
{
    int data;
    struct ListObj* next;
    struct ListObj* prev;
} ListObj;

typedef struct List
{
    struct ListObj* front;
    struct ListObj* back;
    struct ListObj* cursor;
} List;

List newList(void)
{
    List* pL = malloc(sizeof(List));

    if (pL == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pL->front = pL->back = pL->cursor = NULL;

    return *pL;
}

ListObj newListObj(void)
{
    ListObj* pLO = malloc(sizeof(ListObj));

    if (pLO == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pLO->next = pLO->prev = NULL;

    return *pLO;
}

int length(List L)
{
    L.cursor = L.front;
    int n = 0;

    while (L.cursor != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        L.cursor = L.cursor->next;
    }

    return n;
}

void append(List L, int data)
{
    ListObj LO = newListObj();
    LO.data = data;

    if (L.back != NULL)
    {
        LO.prev = L.back;
        L.back->next = &LO;
    }

    L.back = &LO;
    if (L.front == NULL)
    {
        L.front = &LO;
    }

    if (L.front == NULL)
    {
        printf("append null\n");
    }
}

List L = newList();

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (length(L) == 0)
    {
        append(L, i);
    }
}
```

length(L) keeps returning 0, where it should be increasing by 1 each time append() is called.

Comment: You may find [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) helpful.

Comment: The example code is missing a main function, other than that it builds okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using these small improvements:

The prototype:

```
List newList(void);
```

Should be changed to:

```
List  *newList(void);
```

Then the return statement in that function call should be:

```
return pL; //(remove *)
```

This suggestion is the same for the other functions attempting similar usage, such as:  `ListObj newListObj(void)` etc.

Do not forget to free this memory when done using it in the calling function.

The following is basically your code *with no other improvements* ***other than*** addition of a `main()` function with one example call, the suggestions regarding using pointers, and follow-on side-affects of using pointers.  eg, struct pointer notation, freeing, etc.:  ( It builds and runs, but I am not sure these improvements will address other problems the code may have.)

```
List * newList(void)
{
    List* pL = malloc(sizeof(List));

    if (pL == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pL->front = pL->back = pL->cursor = NULL;

    return pL;
}

ListObj * newListObj(void)
{
    ListObj* pLO = malloc(sizeof(ListObj));

    if (pLO == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pLO->next = pLO->prev = NULL;

    return pLO;
}

int length(List *L)
{
    L->cursor = L->front;
    int n = 0;

    while (L->cursor != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        L->cursor = L->cursor->next;
    }

    return n;
}

void append(List *L, int data)
{
    ListObj *LO = newListObj();
    LO->data = data;

    if (L->back != NULL)
    {
        LO->prev = L->back;
        L->back->next = LO;
    }

    L->back = LO;
    if (L->front == NULL)
    {
        L->front = LO;
    }

    if (L->front == NULL)
    {
        printf("append null\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    List *L = newList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (length(L) == 0)
        {
            append(L, i);
        }
    }
    free(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a copy of the dynamically allocated memory object. You should return a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory object instead, and you should be passing the pointers to the dynamically allocated memory objects as parameters of the functions that use them instead of passing copies of the dynamically allocated memory objects.

```
typedef struct ListObj
{
    int data;
    struct ListObj* next;
    struct ListObj* prev;
} ListObj;

typedef struct List
{
    struct ListObj* front;
    struct ListObj* back;
    struct ListObj* cursor;
} List;

List* newList(void)
{
    List* pL = malloc(sizeof(List));

    if (pL == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pL->front = pL->back = pL->cursor = NULL;

    return pL;
}

ListObj* newListObj(void)
{
    ListObj* pLO = malloc(sizeof(ListObj));

    if (pLO == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pLO->next = pLO->prev = NULL;

    return pLO;
}

int length(List* pL)
{
    pL->cursor = pL->front;
    int n = 0;

    while (pL->cursor != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        pL->cursor = pL->cursor->next;
    }

    return n;
}

void append(List* pL, int data)
{
    ListObj* pLO = newListObj();
    pLO->data = data;

    if (pL->back != NULL)
    {
        pLO->prev = pL->back;
        pL->back->next = pLO;
    }

    pL->back = pLO;
    if (pL->front == NULL)
    {
        pL->front = pLO;
    }

    if (pL->front == NULL)
    {
        printf("append null\n");
    }
}

List* pL = newList();

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (length(pL) == 0)
    {
        append(pL, i);
    }
}
```